# Zend CLI Tool issue - php: permission denied?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-tool

today i have recompiled PHP with PDO msql driver and now i cant use Zend CLI tool anymore.
Before Zend CLI tool was working fine, but now i get:

`./zf.sh: 44: php: Permission denied`

I am really out of ideas what is the problem here :/
i have tried changing permsissions, groups, google... but i didnt find any answers for this type of problem :/
Please help if you have any suggestion what should i do :)

Almost forgot:
Ubuntu, PHP 5.3 (as module) on apache 2.0

thanks for your time and reply!

**Edit (PB):** For those wondering, line 44

```
"$PHP_BIN" -d safe_mode=Off -f "$PHP_DIR/zf.php" -- "$@"
```

Comment: What's on line 44 of zf.sh? As a guess, I suspect the account you're using doesn't have the necessary rights to execute the php binary.

Comment: Can you execute PHP itself? Try `/path/to/php -i`

Comment: IMO, Zend Tool is a bigger pain then its worth.

Comment: Thanks for you time guys. Well I can execute php -i from anywhere it is in my environemnt

Answer (score 0):

Why did you recompile php5? You can just compile the required PDO libs as well you know :p.

And AFAIK MSSQL is (or was at least) compatible with the Sybase DB drivers, so you could just as easily use these.

Check out [Install PDO, PDO_SQLITE, PDO_DBLIB, PDO_MYSQL](http://atutility.com/2007/09/14/install-pdo-pdo_sqlite-pdo_dblib-pdo_mysql), it should work for Ubuntu too since it's Debian based.

BTW Just reinstall php5 that came with Ubuntu first, then follow the instructions there.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There was no PHP5 with Ubuntu. I have compiled it a year ago. I tried to load PDO libs from php.ini but i didnt work, so i recompile it, since i needed some other stuff too.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running then? Must be a very old (outdated) one if it didn't come with php5. As for your problem, could it be that AppArmor or SELinux is running on the machine? That could explain weird permission denied errors.